# [Java][XSLT] Replace Map values in all the XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to replace all occurrences of Java map keys to their values.
I'm using xslt 1.0 and don't know how to proceed.

For example:
In java I have a Map,

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
myMap.add("valueToReplace1","valueReplaced1");
myMap.add("valueToReplace2","valueReplaced2");
myMap.add("valueToReplace3","valueReplaced3");
```

An example of input XML

```
<Root>
<attribute1>I want to replace valueToReplace1</attribute1>
<attribute2>
<subAttribute1>I want to replace valueToReplace2
</subAttribute1>
</attribute2>
<attribute3>valueToReplace3</attribute3>
</Root>
```

And what I expect:

```
<Root>
<attribute1>I want to replace valueReplaced1</attribute1>
<attribute2>
<subAttribute1>I want to replace valueReplaced2
</subAttribute1>
</attribute2>
<attribute3>valueReplaced3</attribute3>
</Root>
```

for nom my xls file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="old" />
    <xsl:param name="new" />

    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" name="text" priority="5">

        <xsl:param name="pString" select="." />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$old and contains($pString,$old)">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="concat(substring-before($pString,$old),$new)" />
                <xsl:call-template name="text">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pString"
                        select="substring-after($pString,$old)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pString" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>
```

variables old new would be the key/value of the map.

Someone have an idea on how to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using Java, why are you restricted to XSLT 1.0? In the Java world Saxon 9 is available on Sourceforge and Maven to use XSLT 2 or 3. If you need to use XSLT 1, then it seems that http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.template.xsl (described at http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/index.html) implements replacing various values in one go, you would just need to make sure you get your Java Map into the XSLT as a parameter. It is not clear whether you are looking for details on the Java side or on the XSLT side.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for your answer, I was trying to add as less dependencies as possible and since I work on existing code I was trying to not impact it too much, but maybe the use of XSLT 2 or 3 worth it. I need mode detail for the XSLT side, for java i just need to add the map to parameter. I will try to watch how to use Saxon 9 instead of actual xml transform. Futhermore I don't find any example on how my map can be use with str:replace with XSLT 1. Have you any hint ?

Comment: I am not sure whether you expect to be able to pass in your Java Map to XSLT, I rather think that won't work unless you use Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 where there is, with the XPath 3.1 map type, a direct conversion from Java types to XSLT/Path types possible. As for the use of the `str:replace` template with XSLT 1, I have tried that at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/bFDb2BL, it performs the multiple replacements one an input of the search and replacement terms as an XML/XSLT type (e.g. a result tree fragment) is used.

Comment: As for using Saxon 9 and XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 where you can directly convert a Java `Map<String, String>` map to an XSLT/XPath 3.1 `map(xs:string, xs:string)` parameter using http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmMap.html#makeMap-java.util.Map-, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaGi/0.

Comment: @MartinHonnen So after several tries, I finally used Saxon 9 and XSLT and its working well, thanks a lot !

Comment: @MartinHonnen I've just another issue, I figures out that the map is not processed in the same order than the order I filled the map, even if i use a LinkedHashMap (Java file), so I think the issue is at XSL side, any hint on how I can resolve my problem ?